# Strange bug with Cambria and text variables

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts

I was typesetting a document using Cambria as the main font (don’t ask me why). Then I have noticed a very peculiar bug that almost ruined my whole work. Below I explain step-by-step what I have experienced. (I am not sure which steps are relevant and which are not, so I list them all).

- I have defined a style for the headings, based on Cambria as well.
- I have defined a text variable for the running headers based on a null
  character style, i.e. an invisible style that is only used as target
  for this variable.
- I have selected the headings that were supposed to
  be displayed in the running headers and applied this invisible
  character style.
- The header effectively works.
- Now, some of my headings contain the sequence “thin space” + “tab”. Each
  time when it does so, there are some strange figures (numbers) coming out in the
  header (see the picture).

[image]

You can inspect the [source file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-8GCJ6AuED8f4TBXi8wjMqRljreuAi55&authuser=artemij.keidan%40uniroma1.it&usp=drive_fs) directly, if you want.

After some attempts, I’ve discovered that this behavior pops up with any kind of “special” space, but not with the standard space. The order must be exactly this: “special” space first, tab next, even with some characters intervening in the middle. Moreover, this happens only with Cambria, not with other fonts (even if I haven’t checked them all).

Any idea? Is it Cambria to blame or it’s InDesign?

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug, though it’s impossible to say offhand if it’s a Cambria bug or an InDesign bug. Since text variables are treated as single characters in InDesign and this only appears in the text variable, I’d lean towards an InDesign bug. Have you tried manually inserting the text variable into some copy in the main body text to see if it happens there as well, or if it’s only in master page text that’s affected?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, it happens also in the main text, not only on the master...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it turns out that it's the last version of Cambria to be blamed. I've installed a slightly earlier version and the bug disappeared. So, it's the font, not the app. The bad part is that I cannot give up the newer version since it has some glyphs that were not included in the earlier ones.

Comment: Good sleuthing! Unfortunately it doesn’t look like there’s any way to report font bugs to Microsoft to get them fixed…